# How can I create a PDF with form fields from a collaboratively edited source document?

Tags: pdf, openoffice, documents, forms, google-docs

I want to create a PDF document with a fill-in form. The source of the document is right now Google Docs, so that my team can edit it collaboratively with ease.

However, Google docs doesn't support form fields, so we just use underscores for them, like this:

```
First name: ______________
```

Then, we export to PDF, and using a PDF editor, I add form fields.

This is obviously inefficient, because the PDF editor can't edit paragraphs, and every time we make substantial changes to the source document, I have to re-add the form fields.

I know that Open Office can export to PDF, and it exports form fields correctly. However, [Google docs loses form fields when importing Open Office ODT files](https://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=3d92c8805f7cca44&hl=en).

Is there a better workflow for this? Sharing the ODT file directly some other way and giving up the nice realtime editing features of Google docs?

Comment: I want to SharePoint, but I'm guess ng that's gonna be quite a lot for just one document. Dropbox might work for you.